# Can't use homebrew installed git

Tags: macos, git, path, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I'm encountering a really weird issue when I try to use the latest version of git I just installed via homebrew. `which git` is pointing me to the homebrew install, but calling `git` returns the original version installed with OS X.

I checked first to see the original version I was on.

```
[user@home ~]$ git --version
git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)
```

Then I went to homebrew to install the latest version.

```
[user@home ~]$ brew install git
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/git-2.0.0.mavericks.bottle.2.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring git-2.0.0.mavericks.bottle.2.tar.gz
==> Caveats
The OS X keychain credential helper has been installed to:
  /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain

The 'contrib' directory has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/git-core/contrib

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.0.0: 1324 files, 31M
```

Looks like it worked! Check that it's pointing to the correct git

```
[user@home ~]$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

Should be good, right? Not so fast

```
[user@home ~]$ git --version
git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)
```

That's weird. Am I really pointing to the right git?

```
[user@home ~]$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/git
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  group  27 Jul  3 15:54 /usr/local/bin/git -> ../Cellar/git/2.0.0/bin/git
```

Sure looks like it. Works when I call it manually

```
[user@home ~]$ /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.0.0/bin/git --version
git version 2.0.0
```

But not as `git`

```
[user@home ~]$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
[user@home ~]$ git --version
git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

EDIT: Solved it. `source .bashrc` fixed it. Still curious as to why `which` would return me the correct executable but it wouldn't be called though, if anyone can explain that.

Comment: Not sure exactly what the problem is, but it sounds like you might want to have a look at the current value of `$PATH`.

Comment: if you wanna see all versions of git you have installed use -> which -a git - (which git, just gives you back the path of the first found one in your PATH variable) to see what paths you have in your PATH do a -> echo $PATH

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Shells maintain a cache of the paths where executables were found in the `$PATH` variable. So it cached `/usr/bin/git` rather than `/usr/local/bin/git`, because the latter didn't exist when your shell started. Running `hash -r` in Bash from your current terminal will clear this cache, then the first instance found in `$PATH` should be the one that executes.

Comment: `hash -r` worked for me

Answer (score 5):

I got the exact same problem. Here is my solution.

```
brew uninstall git
# make sure everything is alright, maybe brew will give you some hint
brew doctor
brew update  
brew install git
# magic happen, brew will give you hint /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
# and recommend you run following command
brew doctor
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After that you are done, however you are not able to see any changes when you run `git --version`. Just log out and log back in, run `git --version` again.

Comment: Opening a new Terminal window is sufficient. Alternatively, one could also call `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: These steps were exactly what I needed, and they helped me set my system using the latest version of git. I also discovered another copy of git that I had downloaded from git-scm.com, so I ran the uninstall.sh script to remove that one.  I am all good now, many thanks to Fang and Jens!

Comment: Thanks for the steps. For me, I was automatically able to use git --version without running the last echo command.

Answer (score 1):

When using homebrew to update git on your machine, follow the following steps:

`brew doctor`

Fix the suggested issues

`brew update` if there is a newer version of homebrew available

`brew install git` to download and install git's latest version

running `brew doctor` will let you know that

> **Warning**: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar

executing `brew link git` will result in the error

> Error: Could not symlink bin/git
>
> Target /usr/local/bin/git already exists. You may want to remove it:
>
> rm '/usr/local/bin/git'

`brew link --overwrite git` to overwrite the symlink and point to the git brew installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I simply restarted my Terminal.

Answer (score -1):

My problem was that I had the Mac GitHub app installed. `/usr/local/bin/git` was pointing to the app's version of git, not the Homebrew version. Uninstalling the GitHub app fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Open your terminal. Enter this command.

`sudo nano /etc/paths`

Then copy the following path in top of file.

`/usr/local/git/bin`

Press control+ X and save.

Check `git --version`

Works for me.

Comment: There is no such file `git/bin`. Do you mean `bin/git`? Also, there is no need to add this to your paths – `/usr/local/bin` is already in there.